Use device's biometric authentication in offline-first PWA
I am making a fully offline application using PWA which utilizes the network, when available for data sync. Users will be able to login in online mode and get the token or sessionID which will be stored in the sessionStorage. Now after this first online login whenever the app is reopened, some form of authentication should be there, lets say a PIN.
My first approach was that when the user logs in in online mode, the server send an OTP to the users mobile device and also in the login response. The client stores this in the localStorage. When the user tries to login after the first online login, he will be prompted to enter the OTP which will be matched against the one stored in localStorage and then authenticated. But I realized that this approach is flawed because anyone who has physical access to the device can see the OTP in the localStorage and gain access to the users account.
Then i realized that no matter what I store in the web storage, I won't be able to achieve secure offline authentication using this approach. Let's say I store the hash of the OTP instead of the actual OTP. Attacker can easily look through the code and check which hashing algorithm is being used. Then choose any OTP, create a hash for it, place it in localStorage, and then login using that OTP.
I then decided to use the device's built-in authentication mechanism like faceID or fingerprint to authenticate my Users. I read that Web Authentication API can be used for this.
This is in simple terms what I understood. Not sure I'm correct about this.
We first register with the device's authenticator to generate a public-private key pair. The authenticator returns the public key. We send the public key to the backend server so that it stores it against the current user. Next time we want to authenticate, client will get a challenge from the server, ask the authenticator to sign this challenge using the private key, send the signed challenge to the backend server. The server uses the public key to check whether everything is fine and will authenticate the user. Now my question is :
Can we eliminate the server from this loop and do the public key storing and signature verifying task on the client so that my app can work offline. I tried to come up with possible flaws in this technique but couldn't find any. In this technique we will be exposing the challenge (hardcoded in source code) and public key (stored in web storage). Is that a problem?
